# Angular js - echoing data across multiple html pages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've worked with many languages and environments (predominately iOS & C#) and have always managed to avoid working with scripting languages.  That avoidance streak has come to an abrupt end: as a huge angularjs project was thrown in my lap - now I'm scrambling to understand this very strange world.  Some features are really cool, other techniques have me thoroughly baffled.  I've spent weeks reading tutorials, studying examples and I still cannot solve a relatively simple problem regarding best practices and structure of the code.

This is what I need to do:  I have a form, where the user will input data (for argument's sake, its two  fields of number type.)  I need to have a banner at the top of the page with the sum of the two input fields - that by itself is relatively easy - but the problem for me, is repeating this banner on subsequent pages.

Home page will contain links to:

```
    page 1
    page 2
```

The link to page 2 will not be available until the user inputs data on page 1, forcing the user to visit page 1, first.  The banner element needs to be a separate file.  Page 2 is a passive display of the data, Page 1 is only page that can actively edit the data.

page 1:  would look like this --

```
banner.html (sum of fields A & field B)

input field A
input field B
```

page 2:

```
banner.html (sum of field A & field B)

Lorem Ipsum ....
```

What's the best way to achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an index page with the banner on top, and partials using the same controller. The value of the banner will be a controller variable.

To use partials, inside the index page, you'll need to include the ngRoute module, and the script tag linking to it.

You'll have a div like this.

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

You'll have a partialRoutes.js file looking something like this.

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: './partials/things.html'
    })
    .when('/stuff',{
        templateUrl: './partials/stuff.html'
    })
    .when('/otherstuff',{
        templateUrl: './partials/otherstuff.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
    })
});
```

When you include ngRoute it will look something like this.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Here are the docs for ngRoute. Hope I helped.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would have a service, lets call it `userData`.  Your `inputController` would then write the details of the inputs to the `userData` service.

Your `bannerController` would then be notified of changes to the data in the `userData` service (via `$watch` or `$broadcast`)

This way when you switch pages the `bannerController` should not change and will still display this information

---

Notes:
This relies on you using some kind of AngularJS routing technique such as NGroute or UI Router.  If a hard page navigation is made then the userData will have to be stored server side.

It would probably be better for the banner to stay outside any `ui-view` so that it is unaffected by navigation, but if it is then as the `userData` service will still be alive and holding the correct data when it is recreated it will have access to the same data

Comment: You've given me a lot good things to think about -  I had convinced myself at one point that I actually need to solve this with Directives, but your approach seems a lot simpler and therefore easier.

Comment: That's good.. As a rule of thumb always use services to share data between controllers.  Once you start thinking this way it becomes easier :)

Comment: Question for you:  In creating the service to simply share snippets of data between controllers, do I need to define this service as a factory?  What do you recommend I read regarding services and IIFE format?  Many thanks for allowing me to pick your brain.

Comment: They are basically the same, but I always create them as a factory.  Read this style guide for more information on best practices regarding layout of code etc https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#services

Answer (score -1):

If both pages have same controller, then $scope can be used to achieve this. If pages have different controller, $rootScope can be used to share variables.